# Hex to Dec code calculation

Tags: delphi, math, number-formatting, hex

I have two cards which contains a hex value, I am struggling to find out what kind of algorithm is used ti get the decimal value.

```
8HEX from chip: 0b98c44a    Printed on card: 3491308370
8HEX from chip: 0c96425c    Printed on card: 812204602
```

does any one of you number experts in here find out how it is done, you helped me with this before :)

Comment: What is the card you speak of? Those hex values are nothing like those inputs.

Comment: hex 0b98c44a = dec 194561098. Where did you get 3491308370?

Comment: the cards are special EM cards which outputs the specified hex value, but written on the actual card is the decimal value, the company issued these numbers does not respond to how they calculate the number written on the card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation between the numbers seems to be that the bits of every byte has been reversed.

When you print first pair in binary they are:

```
11010000 00011001 00100011 01010010    = 3491308370
00001011 10011000 11000100 01001010    = 0x0b98c44a
```

The second pair is:

```
00110000 01101001 01000010 00111010    = 812204602
00001100 10010110 01000010 01011100    = 0x0c96425c
```

If you want to know how to convert one number to the other, you should mention which programming language you are using.

Comment: hey, I will take a look, I will come back to you on this one

Comment: thank you, you are correct :)

Earlier i had a case where every second byte was reversed, but this one every 4 byte was reversed.. did not see that one coming

Comment: yeah i forgot to add my developper software, I used delphi but i guessed i was just looking for a general solution since a wider amount of people might be able to answer it :)